# What are the requirements for a foreigner to become an Air Traffic Controller in Sweden?

Tags: air-traffic-control, career, sweden

### Background

I am an Air Traffic Controller (ATCo) working in Greece and I'm looking for information about working in Sweden as a foreign ATCO. I speak Swedish and my wife is of Swedish origin (not a citizen though).

### My question is...

Is it possible for foreigners who know the Swedish language to get a job in ATC in Sweden? Where can I find vacancies for ATCO positions in Sweden?

Comment: @Stelios Adamantidis.I have created the account in order to get answers and to give,if i can.Ive been visiting AVIATION for a long time,before i decide to join.

Comment: @fkoris I've seen your profile when you first created it and was marked as `unregistered`, no hard feelings. :) And welcome to Aviation SE. -*Note:Previous comments removed*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sweden currently has a surplus of controllers, so you are unlikely to find open positions. However, since you are a qualified controller and speak Swedish, you should be qualified to apply for any position that might come up. I suggest you have a look at LFV, which is the largest Swedish ANSP: www.lfv.se/en

Comment: So,there is no nationality-citizenship restrictions for hiring an atc?Are there any openings that might come up in a long term period?My objective is to have succeded working in Sweden  within the next 3-4 years...Thank you for your time and your help..

Comment: Remember that Sweden and Greece are both EU-countries. Nationality based restrictions can be based on "EU-nationals only", but "our country only, no nationals from other EU countries" is illegal in most cases. So in theory there should be no restrictions. Whether or not this is the same in practice can only be answered by an insider, who probably won't admit any bias for legal reasons.